# HtmlAgilityPack - get all nodes in a document

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

i would like to traverse all nodes in a documnet using HtmlAgilityPack 
will

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in myhtml.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//@"))
```

do?

Answer (score 23):

You can just loop through `myhtml.DocumentNode.Descendants()`.

Comment: At least in the current version of HtmlAgilityPack (1.4.9.5), this code won't even compile. Descendants method does not have the overload without parameters.